# What are the arch linux console font color values?

Tags: arch-linux

I really like the console font colors of Arch, and I'd like to set up my X environment with the same theme. What are the color values?

Comment: [Color output in console - ArchWiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Color_output_in_console)

Comment: I know about that wiki page. Maybe I'm overlooking something, but it doesn't help me in finding the actual rgb-values of the font colors.

Comment: You missed "Color scheme scripts

See [2] for scripts which display a chart of your current terminal scheme. "

Comment: I did actually miss that reference, but it doesn't answer the question. These scripts don't return the rgb-values, they just make make a picture using the available colors. I already know what the colors look like. I'm looking for the rgb-values.

Comment: There are programs that will return the RGB values for points on the screen ...